# Parent with relative positioned child moves with child in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, position, css-position

I've set up a `<nav>` which contains an unordered list of links, and set a 10px border on each `<li>`.

Because the font I am using has a large amount of space above each character, I've set `position: relative` on the links, and pushed them upwards by 6 pixels so they're tight to the border from the parent `<li>`.

This works fine everywhere except IE7 (and possibly below), where the whole `<li>` and its child `<a>` appears to push upwards by 6 pixels, which knocks my navigation out of position.

Here's a jsfiddle to show my code: http://jsfiddle.net/SD3Xj/

If you want to see the live site to see how it looks in IE7 it's at http://jasonbradberry.com

Any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Jason, I've tried your website in 3 different browsers, the navigation looks fine to me. The only thing I can think of is the padding you have on the header at top. I'm I mising something?

Comment: Imran, thanks - I've tested in IE7 via https://browserlab.adobe.com/ and it shows the navigation higher than it should - the borders overlap the header background instead of sitting flush below. I can see that the problem is because the -6px relative positioning appears to be applying to the parent `<li>` and not the child `<a>` to which I applied it, so far as I can see.

Comment: Sorry, looking again, it is applying the -6px relative positioning to _both_ the parent `<li>` and the child `<a>`. The `<a>` is showing in the correct position, but the parent element has moved, and it is the parent element that has the border applied to it, so the border is out of place.

Comment: did you try my answer? I made a copy of your home page on my local computer and tested it with some CSS changes and it worked in IE7 including Firefox as well as IE8. An up vote would be much appreciated if you won't accept the answer as it took me about 45 minutes to work out what the issue was.

Answer (score 0):

These CSS rules will fix the issue you are having:

```
nav { margin-top: -80px; padding-bottom: 33px; }

nav ul { float: right; position: relative; }

nav li { float:left; display:inline; border-top: 10px solid #7a7a7a; margin-right: 16px; }

nav li.active { border-top: 20px solid #29cf86;}

nav a {}
```

Just simply replace the CSS rules with the ones above.